# TeamCity - Get Build Server Log | Currently Build

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, devops, teamcity-9.0

I am using TeamCity build server for my CI process. I have a scenario, where i need to compare my previous and current build log and check for warnings in the code ad if the warnings count in the current is greater than the previous build, we have to fail the build.

I have two build steps namely:

- For MS build
- A powershell script to compare the builds ( previous build and current build)

I understand we can get the build information using the TeamCity API which is **http:// /httpAuth/downloadBuildLog.html?BuildId=<< current build id >>**

Is there anyway to get the build log while the build is in running state, and pass on to my second step ?